Which is the correct form to fill in the gap: "are / am / be / is"?
My friend, as well as I, _______ ready to accompany you in your company.
A) are
B) am
C) be
D) is
Could you explain me which answer correct is?

What do you think yourself?

ask yourself what the subject of the sentence is. Also, try removing as much as you can without altering the most basic meaning of the sentence.

By the way, you don't have to say accompany you in your company. That is just repetitive. "In your company" is what accompany means. Just say, ready to accompany you.

"as well as" is a form of comparison; it is not the same as "and".

Don't make a rod for your own back. Even native speakers can't agree on whether to use a singular or plural verb form in constructions like He, as well as his family, is / are... Just sidestep the problem with He and his family are..., the same as all sensible speakers / writers. Ignore that "form of comparison" business. It's never worth trying to include "hypothetical nuances" if they destroy the flow of your text.
